Old lamp plug has ribbed white and smooth white wires. Both tabs are the same size. Which wire to the side with a larger slot?
I am rewiring an older lamp.
Using white lamp cord.
Can ohm out socket to the smooth wire is on the
light bulb socket center pin for the base and
ribbed wire in on the threads of the base.
It is to be used by my daughter and I don’t want
to see her get shocked.
So my question is, do I insert the plug into the
wall socket such that the lamp plug has the smooth
white wire or the ribbed white wire in the outlet
side with the larger slot?

for safety reason replace that plug immediately, with one that can only be plugged one way (different size blades)

presumably, if this lamp was initially wired to be plug in 2 ways, it should be safe and not rely on "polarity" (as is typically the case in large parts of the world)

Convention is that (a) the ribbed side is neutral, (b) the threaded part of the socket is neutral and (c) the larger pin/slot in a plug/receptacle is neutral.
Since you have (a) and (b) matching, connect the ribbed side to the larger pin/slot and you are all set. Of course, if the plug has two pins of the same side then there is nothing to enforce that. Which means that unless you replace the cord/plug with a polarized cord/plug, there is nothing to enforce (c).
There are two key issues to consider:

Bulb replacement

Bulb replacement is where the configuration of hot/neutral for light bulb sockets matters the most. The threaded part of a light bulb socket presents a far greater contact area for fingers than the center, so by matching the threaded part to neutral you significantly decrease the danger of accidental contact when changing a light bulb. In a perfect world you would turn off the switch (if wired correctly that interrupts the hot wire, so no current can flow in the socket) or unplug the lamp, but for a variety of reasons that is not always done and so neutral = threaded, hot = center is an important safety mechanism.
In the case of a plug-in lamp, unless the receptacle is blocked by heavy furniture (which does happen quite a bit), unplugging the lamp for bulb replacement solves the problem very easily. With LED bulbs, replacement should only be needed once every few years.

Exposed Metal

Exposed metal parts on a lamp may be connected to hot, neutral or ground. With an ungrounded plug, which is normal on plug-in lamps, that just leaves hot and neutral. Neutral is much safer than hot, for obvious reasons. But a lamp will work perfectly fine with hot and neutral reversed, so if it is not wired correctly or is plugged in "backwards" then you won't find out that the metal is hot if something goes wrong, which would be a very bad thing. So if there is any exposed metal (the inside of the bulb socket is covered by the bulb in use; the outside is often covered by plastic or other non-conductive material, but not always) then check for continuity with the plug pins. If any exposed metal has continuity with the neutral pin then that's normal but then you need to make sure the plug is used correctly. If any exposed metal has continuity with the hot pin, STOP and don't use the lamp without fixing it.
